# Calculating robustness of layout plans

Tags: optimization, robust-optimization

We have tried to design a manufacturing cell which will produce specific families of products. We figure out three layout plans for implementation. For practical reasons, we need to calculate the robustness of plans.

AFAIK, one reasonable way to do that is to use the statistical method such as Monte Carlo simulation. To use this method we have to define three main steps.

- The first step is to identify the transfer equation.
- The second step is to define the input parameters.
- The last step creating random data.

Finally, there will be an analysis of output for each input data. Our goal is to define the transfer equation based on minimizing delay, transfer time and workers for each product.

**My questions are:**

1) Is our method suitable to calculate the robustness of plans?

2) Would you know other methods to do that which aren't complicated?